# SoftAssert in Selenium Test Class

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a test method inside a test class where I want to verify a couple things, only fail after I soft assert in this specific test method.

But, I feel my test method is getting messy with failure handling.  I haven't been able to find any best practices on this.  Any ideas? If I move the asserts into the page object class, it will be a bit messy there too.

```
@Test
public void test() {

    // steps here

    // then asserts here
    SoftAssert soft = new SoftAssert();
    String expectedHeaderText = "foo";

    soft.assertTrue(pageObjectClass.isHeaderPresent(), "Unable to find the Header page object.");


    soft.assertTrue(pageObjectClass.getHeader().contains(expectedHeaderText),
            String.format("Expected to find '%s'.  Page actually shows '%s'", expectedHeaderText, pageObjectClass.getHeader()));

    // more asserts

    sa.assertAll();

}
```

Comment: It seems rather redundant to check for the presence of the header, and then check the text in the header. If you drop out the first assert, and just check for the header text, you're still asserting the same thing: that the header is present and the text is what you expect. 

Keep asserts in the test class, never in the page object class as that doesn't make sense. The page object class should just have selectors and getters/setters and other page related logic, no assertions should be done there.

Answer (score 1):

Check below convention

```
@Test
public void test() {
// steps here

// then asserts here
SoftAssert soft = new SoftAssert();
String expectedHeaderText = "foo";

Boolean checkHeader=pageObjectClass.isHeaderPresent() //Change the method on POM pageObjectClass such that it returns the true or false
soft.assertTrue(checkHeader,true);

String checkHeaderContent=pageObjectClass.getHeader()//change method on POM pageObjectClass to return a string
soft.assertTrue(checkHeaderContent.contains(expectedHeaderText), String.format("Expected to find '%s'.  Page actually shows '%s'", expectedHeaderText, checkHeaderContent));
// more asserts
sa.assertAll();
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, so if I have 5 more of these inside the test method, is it going to look too repetitive? ie, check header, then header text, then move to checking another item and its text, repeat a few times.   I was thinking if inside the 'isHeaderPresent' we return a true/false AND a error message?

Comment: I can think of many ways to implement your scenario. I would suggest you to pass the "expectedHeaderText" to POM method that would check both presence ,header content and return true/false based on findings!

Comment: if I check for present and content in the POM method and return true/false then I would lose out failure messages since the method returns true/false.  Unless I keep all the failure message content in the test method

Comment: Makes sense,better have it in the test class!

Answer (score 0):

You can check [QMetry Automation Framework](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf) which provided [assertion and verification](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/assertion_verification.html) methods. For example:

```
//verify element present 
firstName.verifyPresent();
firstName.assertPresent();

//verify Text of Element
firstName.verifyText("First User");
firstName.assertText("First User");

//verify Text of element with StringMatchers conditions
firstName.verifyText(StringMatcher.contains("First User"));
firstName.assertText(StringMatcher.contains("First User"),"Username Validation");
```

In case of assert method, your test will not continue on assert fail.

In case of any verify method, your test will continue even if verification failed and the final status of test will be failed if one or more verification failed.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a dilemma: to have explicit checks and readable error messages, or omit something in order to make the code shorter or more generic to be reused.

Your example is a plain SoftAssert usage which is recommended by many tutorials.

It's a best practice to keep all assertions on Test Level, not in Page Objects.

But how to deal when you see, some assertions are huge and duplicated within several test methods?

I suggest following next rules:

- Similar(duplicated) assert constructions can be moved to a new *helper* method within a current Test Class.
- Try to split the tests into classes in the way, test classes contain only similar test methods.
- If several test classes contain the same code, you can create a common parent for a group of classes and move some reusable code on this *test-class-group* level.
- Do not try to fully avoid duplications on Test Level, tests are something that is changed and outdated rapidly. They should be still readable and easy to understand what happens in the code.

I don't use SoftAsserts, but can suggest some of this as a point for the extension:

```
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert

import static java.lang.String.format

public class ProjectSoftAssert extends SoftAssert {

    public void assertElementVisibleAndContainsText(
            boolean isVisible, String actualText, String expectedText, String elementName
    ) {
        assertTrue(isVisible, format("Unable to find the '%s' page object.", elementName));
        assertTrue(
                actualText.contains(expectedText),
                format(
                        "Wrong '%s' page object text. Expected to find '%s'. Page actually shows '%s'",
                        elementName, expectedText, actualText
                )
        );
    }

}
```

And in your scenario:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    // steps here
    // then asserts here
    ProjectSoftAssert soft = new ProjectSoftAssert();
    soft.assertElementVisibleAndContainsText(
            pageObjectClass.isHeaderPresent(), pageObjectClass.getHeader(), "foo", "Header"
    );
    // more asserts
    soft.assertAll();
}
```